# Firebase Database is not showing data

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase console dose not show any data if I go to rules then also it is not showing rules also it is just showing unable to show rules what should I do?

[image: firebase console and an excerpt of my data]

Comment: At the top-right, there is a circle-shaped button with a plus inside. Use it to expand the data tree.

Comment: I have tried it. the point is that I am not able to view my data tree, but when I export my data to json its is there

Comment: We can't access to your Firebase dashboard. Can you screenshot?

Comment: have just edited and included an image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it might seem ridiculous but I have tried to log out and log in but it didn't help so i changed the web browser and it worked

Comment: What browser did you use that it worked, I'm having the same problem, and tried any browsers, still nothing.

Comment: I have tried firefox and internet explorer

Comment: @zxnet did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes using various browsers save the problem

Comment: this was your ad-blocker... most likely.

Comment: I tried multiple web browsers (Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Explorer) but the data is not getting loaded. Tried to disable the ad blocker, log out & log in, cleared the cache, and deleted the cookies but no luck at all.
Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. It was the Ads blocker. Just I disabled it and data showed up.

Be careful of these sneaky extensions.

Hope it helps others.

Comment: thanks . this is my problem and I have just solved it .

Comment: not work for me

Answer (score 3):

just goto the RULES option given beside the data in Firebase and change the read,write from false to true and then click simulator and publish it.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this problem and try this.

1. Log out of your Google account.
2. Close every instance of the browser.
3. Restart your laptop.
4. Log into the console.

This has helped me numerous times and it might work for you too.