# user info don't load after login using the new firebase. iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm new in programming and still learning in swift language.

I hope you could help me with this issue.

when I try to signup the Userinfo shows in database but when I try to login the user info disappears why is that so? can't figure it out.

### Here is how i signup

```
@objc func handleSignUp() {

    guard let username = usernameField.text else { return }

    guard let email = emailField.text else { return }

    guard let pass = passwordField.text else { return }

    guard let image = profileImageView.image else { return }

    setContinueButton(enabled: false)
    continueButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    activityView.startAnimating()
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: pass) { user, error in

        if error == nil && user != nil {
            print("User created!")


            // 1. Upload the profile image to Firebase Storage

            self.uploadProfileImage(image) { url in
                if url != nil {
                    let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
                    changeRequest?.displayName = username
                    changeRequest?.photoURL = url
                    changeRequest?.commitChanges { error in

                        if error == nil {
                            print("User display name changed!")

                            self.saveProfile(username: username, profileImageURL: url!) { success in
                                if success {
                                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                                } else {
                                    self.resetForm()
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            print("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                            self.resetForm()
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    self.resetForm()
                }
            }
        } else {
            self.resetForm()
        }
    }
}
```

### And here is how I log in

```
@objc func handleSignIn() {


    guard let email = emailField.text else { return }
    guard let pass = passwordField.text else { return }


    setContinueButton(enabled: false)
    continueButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    activityView.startAnimating()

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: pass) { user, error in

        if error == nil && user != nil {

            self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

            _ = Auth.auth().currentUser

        } else {
            print("Error logging in: \(error!.localizedDescription)")

            self.resetForm()
        }
    }
```

### I don't know what seems to be the problem

Comment: Your `handleSignIn` doesn't seem to do anything with the database. Where does the user info disappear from when you run that method?

Comment: yes.when I run the log in method the user info don't show on database. but when I try signing up the user info shows. why does this happen? any pointers or answer?

Comment: `Firebase` signIn method is just for authentication and it does nothing with database So you will have to fetch the data corresponding to `Auth.auth().currentUser.uid` after successfully logged in.

Comment: how can I do that? can you show me a few lines of code?

Comment: @JohnKennethParalejas Could you please show the screenshot of your database?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430820/swift-firebase-how-do-i-properly-store-a-facebook-user-into-firebase-database for an example of how to store user information in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with firebase but according to their documentation this is "da way" :

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("ERROR [ signIn ] => \(error)")
        // self.resetForm()
    } else {
        if let user = user {
            let uid = user.uid
            let email = user.email
            print("Authorised User => \(uid) ... \(email)")
        }
    }
}
```

If after trying the above code and you see this output `ERROR [ signIn ] => whatever error..."`, then it's your signIn that failed. If you see this output `Authorised User => SomeUID ... SomeEMAIL`, then you signed in successfully and your user's data is still in the database.

I hope this helps you find "da way"

**If all else fails:**

You can change browsers and check your database again ? Try a couple of browsers. This worked for [some people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583502/firebase-database-is-not-showing-data)

Good luck!

Comment: I just signed in successfully but there's still no sign of data inside the database.is that normal?

Comment: what was the output ?

Comment: Authorised User => EDFmizAisVWcJT56d7BVAtDjo5r1 ... Optional("kenneth@p.com")

Comment: @John Kenneth Paralejas I have one more guess. Can you change browsers and check your database again ? Try a couple of browsers. This worked for [some people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583502/firebase-database-is-not-showing-data)